# Extending parent blocks from included template, looking for a workaround

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a site with some ajax pages. If user types in a browser `/login/`, he should get a full rendered template, extended from a base template. But if user clicks a login button, `$('#content').ajax('/login/');` called, so i don't need to render a full template.

I.e. i have this (`login_ajax.html`):

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}
    {% trans "Login" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "social.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

In `login.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block ajax_content %}
{% include "login_ajax.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Simple login view:

```
def login(request):
    c = Context({'user': request.user})

    if request.is_ajax():
        return render_to_response('login_ajax.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response('login.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This problem refers to documentation of include tag:

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render
>   this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate
>   and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means
>   that there is no shared state between included templates – each
>   include is a completely independent rendering process.

But i don't want to place `title` name in a view, or place it twice in `login.html` and `login_ajax.html` also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move `{% block title %}` back out into `login.html` then make two ajax calls. One to override `{% block ajax_content %}` and one to override `{% block title %}`. You could use the same pattern for overriding `{% block title %}` as you've used for overriding `{% block ajax_content %}`, but you'd probably manage without actually creating a new `title.html` template.

I can't see any other way round your problem.

Comment: {% block title %} is already in `login_ajax.html`. And I need `login.html` to extend from "base.html". It means, that if request is_ajax, it will return just login_ajax.html, if not, `login.html` will include common code from `login_ajax.html` and extend from `base.html`, what will give the whole page. Also, if you see simpler solution, i'll be glad if you point me on it.

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand the problem. What error are you actually getting? Is there text in your output page that shouldn't be there? Is there text that should be but isn't? Is there something in your output page that's displaying wrong?

Comment: When render `login.html` I need to get `{% block content %}` from `login_ajax.html` been rendered in `base.html`. But according to documentation blocks from included templates are ignored, so i need another way to redefine the parent's block from included template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found a simple solution. In fact, the problem is in question: "to extend from base, or not to extend".

In fact, i don't care a template from what `login.html` should be extended. So, for ajax request, the parent template will be `empty.html`, and for default request, it will be `base.html`. So, i'll point a parent template in the view:

```
def login(request):
    c = Context({'user': request.user, 'extends': 'empty.html'})

    if request.is_ajax():
        return render_to_response('login.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    c['extends'] = 'base.html'
    return render_to_response('login.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The `empty.html` just contain a placeholder for a block:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

And here is `login.html`:

```
{% extends extends %}
{% load i18n %}

{% if extends != 'empty.html' %}
    {% block title %}{% trans "Login" %}{% endblock %}
{% else %}
    <div style="display: none;" class="ajax-title">{% trans "Login" %}</div>
{% endif %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "social.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Also, i suppose, there is a way to turn `login.html` into a snippet, that could be included using with. i.e. `{% include 'snippet.html' with extends='base.html' %}`